# Generar arreglo de aleatorios

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, bucles, random

Quería llenar una arreglo de 5 elementos donde genere números aleatorios sin repetir, pero me sigue imprimiendo números aleatorios repetidos. Explico mi código

```
int arreglo_aleatorio[5];//Creo un arreglo de 5 enteros

srand(time(NULL));//Inicio de generar random

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<(i+1);j++){
        arreglo_aleatorio[i] = 1 + rand() % (6 - 1);//agregar random a la posición "i" de mi arreglo
        while(arreglo_aleatorio[i]==arreglo_aleatorio[j] && i!=j){ //Mientras el arreglo sea igual al de j, y "i" y "j" sean diferentes para saber que no es la misma posición del arreglo (porque obviamente sería el mismo número)
            arreglo_aleatorio[i] = 1 + rand() % (6 - 1);//Que genere un random hasta que sean diferentes
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){//Imprimir el arreglo para comprobar si funciona
    cout<<arreglo_aleatorio[i]<<endl;
}
```

**Después de todo esto ,sigue teniendo números repetidos.**

No sé si tengo un error, o me pueden recomendar otro código mejor

Answer (score 8):

Estás enfocando el problema mal.

---

Ahora mismo tu algoritmo pretende crear cinco números aleatorios entre el uno y el cinco sin que se repita ninguno de ellos; para ello:

1. Generas un número.
2. Miras si el número había sido ya generado.
3. Si es así vuelves al primer punto, en caso contrario lo guardas.

Este algoritmo puede potencialmente ser infinito y cuantos más números hayas guardado más probabilidad de generar un número repetido.

[Dale la vuelta al algoritmo](https://tio.run/##bU/bSgMxEH3efMWAYDcQwVqLdHfxR1RKTGbTQDZTJokvpd@@xm5BxL7NuXDmHHM8Ppigo5vnOx9NKBZh8JQyo55exS/HOlr6w@jgiH0@VFL4mGHSPrZSnETzgzQzukB7HVDn6qP09gGntYInBRsFzwq2514IaFK2Xbek7y1@eYPAthcLP@X1brd5AdeybaXsBVyFdCjjGLC9gE909fX/j1LBRcdob6tuSRyJoTUUU61dMsF9LBMyQXdjhRTN0sBQyTAMcPXWa/UeV3VSw5gLR3jsxXmevwE):

1. Genera números del uno al cinco.
2. Desordénalos.

```
int arreglo_aleatorios[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

 std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
 
std::shuffle(std::begin(arreglo_aleatorios), std::end(arreglo_aleatorios), g);
 
for (const auto &numero : arreglo_aleatorios)
    std::cout << numero << '\n';
```

No puedes tener números repetidos si partes de un arreglo sin repeticiones.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Debes sacar tu linea 7 y ponerla en la 6, ya que pertenece al otro for de forma en la que lo compararía con todos, lo que pasa con tu código es que conforme tu segundo ciclo (for) avanza el arreglo_aleatorio[i] también se cambia. Este debería ser calculado una única vez.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    arreglo_aleatorio[i] = 1 + rand() % (6 - 1);
    for(int j=0;j<(i+1);j++){
        while(arreglo_aleatorio[i]==arreglo_aleatorio[j] && i!=j){
            arreglo_aleatorio[i] = 1 + rand() % (6 - 1);
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){//Imprimir el arreglo para comprobar si funciona
    cout<<arreglo_aleatorio[i]<<endl;
}
```