# ¿como agregar no numeros repetidos y utilizando un rand?

Tags: c++

¿como agregar no números repetidos y utilizando un random ?
hace el ciclo vuelve agregar numero que ya esta

**IMPRESION**

> ```
> inserte el tamaño del arreglo: 10
> insercion 2
> 2 
> insercion 4
> 2 4 
> insercion 4
> 2 4 4 
> insercion 18 
> 2 4 4 18 
> insercion 2
> 2 2 4 4 18
> insercion 9
> 2 2 4 4 9 18 
> insercion 13
> 2 2 4 4 9 13 18 
> insercion 13
> 2 2 4 4 9 13 13 18
> ```

```
#include "list.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  int b;
  cout<<"inserte el tamaño del arreglo: ";
  cin>>b;
    list secuencias(b);
    srand((unsigned)time(nullptr));


  for(int i=1;i<2*b;i++){
    int x = rand()% 20+1;
    if (rand()%(2*b)+1){
      printf("insercion %i\n",x);
      secuencias.ins(x);
    }else{
      printf("extracion %i\n",x);
      secuencias.del(x);
    }
  secuencias.print();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int x = rand() % 20 + 1;
    printf("Busca %i\n",x);
        secuencias.find(x);
    printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**¿Cómo puedo ayudar que agregue números no repetidos?**.

Comment: Chavo, parte de que sean numeros al azar implica que se van a repetir en algun punto. Sobre todo si solo dejas que sean numeros del 1 al 20. Lo que puedes hacer es un array, y mesclarlo para que los numeros parezcan aleatorios

Comment: Como dice @Pablochaches, lo mas sencillo, es llenar de datos el `array` y barajarlo con el metodo [shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/)..

Comment: como es shuflle?

Comment: Puedes darle al link que el puso, [o a este](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). Si por algun motivo no te dejan usar el STL en este hay una implementaciones ejemplo que te pueden servir.

Comment: Puedes comprobar si hay algún elemento repetido con if's, else's y bucles.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que estás programando en C++ y dado que has etiquetado tu pregunta como tal, deberías estar usando la cabecera de generación de números pseudoaleatorios del lenguaje: [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random). Para generar números aleatorios entre 1 y 20 lo harías así:

```
std::random_device dispositivo;
std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(1, 20);

int aleatorio = distribucion(generador);
```

Tienes tres opciones para evitar repetir números en una colección de números aleatorios:

1. Genera el número, pero no lo guardes si ya está presente:

   ```
   std::list<int> numeros;

   while (numeros.size() != b)
   {
       int aleatorio = distribucion(generador);
       auto found = std::find(numeros.begin(), numeros.end(), aleatorio);

       if (found == numeros.end())
       {
           numeros.push_back();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Usa un contenedor que no admita repeticiones:

   ```
   std::set<int> numeros;

   while (numeros.size() != b)
   {
       numeros.insert(distribucion(generador));
   }
   ```
3. [Parte de una lista sin repeticiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379974/generar-arreglo-de-aleatorios/380044#380044), y desordénala.

   ```
   std::list<int> numeros(20, 0);
   std::generate(numeros.begin(), numeros.end(), [i = 0]() mutable { return ++i; });

   std::shuffle(numeros.begin(), numeros.end(), generador);
   ```